# R : From main script, call external subroutine R scripts to avoid waiting on subroutine

Tags: r, sql-server, parallel-processing

## Problem

I have an analysis workflow whereby participant computers perform simulation and subsequent analysis on several tasks in parallel using standard `doParallel` implementation. The participant computers coordinate by communicating with a remote SQL server to reserve tasks to complete, and mark them completed when done.

The computers are running into delays because the server is slow to process all of the queries and transactions sent to it. Since there is a wait time due to the high traffic, the participant computers -- as they are currently programmed -- will not move on to the next set of tasks until all of their tasks are marked complete, sometimes waiting for hours.

## Question/Solution

I would prefer to have a subroutine handle the SQL communications, particularly updating complete, so that the main analysis loop isn't waiting for those transactions to complete before going to get more tasks.

How can I call a sub R script from the main one in a separate session, such that the main script is not concerned with waiting for the subroutine to finish?

- If I used `system(cmd = "R PATHTOSCRIPT.R")`, will that spawn a distinct Rsession, or will it operate within the same one?
- I envision a single call to the script before the analysis loop, that perhaps runs at pre-defined intervals to update tasks that have been completed.

#### Notes

I can't use `source()` because that would make the main script wait for the subroutine to finish.

#### Packages

I use `DBI` and `odbc` to manage the SQL transactions, with `dbExecute()` to perform SQL transactions wrapped in error handling for automatic retries after `rpois(5)` seconds.

Comment: Something sounds wrong if your DB is taking hours to respond. What version of SQL Server are you using? Is this a prod machine?

Comment: Hi @HongOoi, I'm hosting the server on gearhost.com, and they use SQL Server 13.0.4451, or so MSSQL Server Management Studio says. I've opened a support ticket with them. To clarify - there are always transactions going, it's just that some of the computers are constantly selected as victims in the deadlocks, perhaps having something to do with the way the server prioritizes transaction sources (I've noticed that it seems to disfavor newer computers making transactions, but that's anecdotal.)

Answer (score 0):

With some testing, I have decided that the `system(command, invisible = F, wait = F)` call to a `.bat` file with the subroutines is best. A separate process is started, and a CMD window opens to indicate to the user what it is doing.

The `.bat` file is to make the subroutine easily restarted by users upon accidental closure of the CMD window.